# I'm having problems restarting httpd server due to segfault in libapr

Tags: httpd, segmentation-fault

My httpd server has stopped working, within /var/log/messages I got the following error:

May 10 08:08:30 linuxbox kernel: httpd[25353]: segfault at b7fb7991 ip 009ca63b sp bfec3d50 error 7 in libapr-0.so.0.9.12[9af000+1f000]

Can anyone shed light on how to fix this, i've tried ghosting the drive, then removed apr and re-installed, but the error keeps coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem in the future, check out /usr/lib/httpd/modules as one possibility, I found that some of the modules stopped it from working (in my case mod_authz_svn.so and mod_dav_svn.so)